# How would I parse a polynomial?

Tags: python, parsing, polynomials

I was wondering what the best way to parse an equation from a string would be? For example, the string `'2x^2+7x-3'` is a polynomial expression.

I would like to do this in such a way that there are 3 variables - a, b and c - and they hold the coefficient of the x^2 term, the x term as well as the integer on the end, respectively. The coefficients should include the corresponding signs, as they can be positive or negative.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post what code you've tried so far, what your current output is, and what your expected output is. For more information, please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The word you are looking for is "parsing".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sympy`

import sympy

```
my_poly = "2*x**2+7*x-3"
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
my_poly = sympy.polys.polytools.poly_from_expr(my_poly)[0]
a, b, c = poly.coeffs()
```

Side note. The expression in `my_poly` has to follow python syntax for expressions. If your strings do not, you can use string manipulation techniques to correct them.

Comment: "poly" in line 4 should be "my_poly"

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

eqn = '2x^2+7x-3'

# add a leading 1 where necessary
eqn = '1'+eqn if not eqn[0].isdigit() else eqn

#remove all powers
no_carets = re.sub(r"(\^\d+)", "", eqn)

# get numeric coefficients
raw_coeffs = re.findall(r'[\d\.\-\+]+', no_carets)

# add a 1 to lone signs and convert coefficients to float
coeffs = [float(x+'1') if len(x) is 1 and not x.isdigit() else float(x) for x in raw_coeffs]
```

Edit: Please note that this solution comes with caveats (will work only for numeric values of coefficients, can have misleading results for missing powers, etc) and hence you'll have to exercise discretion in such cases.

Comment: This will give misleading results for polynomials like `x^3+2`.

Comment: I agree and realize this has many caveats, and preprocessing for `sympy` would probably be the better solution.